# Algolia Autocomplete Linking with Multiple Indices

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, algolia

I have set up Algolia's autocomplete.js to search through multiple indices (‘resources’ and ‘users’). I want the link when a user clicks on a ‘resource’ to be different from when a user clicks on a 'user.'

Using Algolia's documentation for a jQuery implementation, I have the following:

```
$('#aa-search-input').autocomplete(
  {
    hint: true,
    minLength: 2,
  }, [
    {
      source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(resources, { hitsPerPage: 3 }),
      displayKey: 'name',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Resources</div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<span>' +
          suggestion._highlightResult.name.value + '</span><span>'
          + suggestion._highlightResult.write_up.value + '</span>';
        },
      empty: '<div class="aa-empty">No matching resources <i class="frown icon"></i></div>',
    }
  },
  {
    source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(users, { hitsPerPage: 3 }),
      displayKey: 'name',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Users</div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<span>' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.username.value + '</span>';
          },
      empty: '<div class="aa-empty">No matching users <i class="frown icon"></i></div>',
      }
    }
  ]).on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
    location.href = '/resources/view/show-' + suggestion.id;
});
```

How could I apply the **.on('autocomplete.selected)** function to each of the two **sources** separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've put an example for you that explains how to do so [here](https://codepen.io/Haroenv/pen/goYjOP/?editors=1011).

```
on("autocomplete:selected", function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
  // 1-indexed dataset
  var url = datasets[dataset-1].url
  // do something with:
  console.log(url, suggestion);
  // for example
  // location.href = url + suggestion.objectID
});
```

If you have any other questions, you can also take a look at the Discourse [forum](https://discourse.algolia.com/t/using-autocomplete-with-multiple-indices-and-different-links/3907).

Comment: With a little fandangling to match my specific use case, that worked beautifully. Thank you!